# attach files to email without saving content to local file

Tags: email, elixir

I am using elixir [Bamboo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo) for sending emails

I have some binary content and would like to attach to email

the simple way is:

```
content = <<binary-content>>
File.write("/tmp/myfile.pdf", content )
data = new_email()
  |> to(email)
  |> from( "email.com")
  |> subject("subject")
  |> put_attachment("/tmp/myfile.pdf")
  |> put_header("Reply-To", "email.com")
  |> html_body(html_body)
File.rm("/tmp/myfile.pdf", content )
```

is there a way attach files without saving them locally?
something like:

```
content = <<binary-content>>
data = new_email()
  |> to(email)
  |> from( "email.com")
  |> subject("subject")
  |> put_attachment(content)
  |> put_header("Reply-To", "email.com")
  |> html_body(html_body)
```

Comment: I don't think they support it yet but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You bet. It was included prior to the 1.0 release. You can attach data directly to the struct as [of this PR](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo/commit/d09da6a9f8c34b969491cca7dd52d10161e94f68).

You just need to pass put_attachment a Bamboo Attachment struct with the data field populated, so:

```
content = <<binary-content>>
data = new_email()
  |> to(email)
  |> from( "email.com")
  |> subject("subject")
  |> put_attachment(%Bamboo.Attachment{filename: "filename.example", data: content})
  |> put_header("Reply-To", "email.com")
  |> html_body(html_body)
```

Here's the thread on the feature: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo/issues/286